# Send JS-Ajax to C# or Java

Tags: javascript, java, c#, csv, parsing

I have a import function for CSV files in my PHP application. But the scaling is so horrible(~4 rows per second) that i want to switch it to some faster running solution. Before some people argue that my code must be messed up because its kinda slow... no its because i check every row if its a duplicate in some way and try to merge data.

Is there a way to send the data via JavaScript to a program that is listening on a local port or something like that? I dont like the idea of Servlet tho.

I've never done something like that, are there security issues i should be aware of?

Comment: Why would you read the csv files with php and send them to java over the network instead of just reading the files from java (or whatever) directly?

Comment: @xander i want to do that :D but the user will upload the file through the PHP application. I mean i also could just save the file somewhere and let the background service that runs every 15min do the job. But i think that solution is somewhat ugly and unresponsive.

Comment: you know there is something like a file system watcher, when a new file is added to a directory or whatever it fires an event and you can react to that, just saying that might be easier. obvioulsy there are ways to communicate over the network, but then you need a web server that is listening for incoming requests and that is not that easy :)

Comment: @xander yeah thought so already. I will have a look at the file system watcher. A different solution would also be to start the process via PHP and "proc_open()".